# How to correct the error: 'Book' object has no attribute 'worksheets' by pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a method which given an excel file path returns sheet names and their state of visible or hidden as well as sheet number as index. I created the following codes but when running worksheets is not found from Book object. I upgraded 'xlsxwriter' library but it did not help.

```
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(excel_path)
    sheets = xls.book.worksheets
    i=0
    sheet_states=[]
    for sheet in sheets:
        sheet_states.append([sheet.title,sheet.sheet_state])
        # print(i,sheet.title, sheet.sheet_state)
        i+=1
    sheet_states_df=pd.DataFrame(sheet_states,columns=["title","state"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas 2.0.3:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                              
                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                 
def get_sheet_info(file_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:                                                                      
    work_book = pd.ExcelFile(path_or_buffer=file_path)                                        
    sheets = work_book.book.worksheets                                                                           
                                                                                                                 
    data = [{"title": sheet.title, "state": sheet.sheet_state, "index": idx} for idx, sheet in enumerate(sheets)]

    return pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```